# Combining numbers into one Java variable

Tags: java

I am trying to make a program that, depending on an int called `length`, adds a certain number of 9s to a variable called `nines`. For example, if `length` is 4 then I want `nines` to equal 9999. If `length` is 7, I want `nines` to equal 9999999. The value of `length` needs to correspond to the number of nines in `nines.` Is this possible, and if so, how?

Comment: Make it with a String, then parse back. Be aware though that an int cannot hold too many digits.

Comment: That would work also. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it is possible: observe that your target number is ten to the power of Length, minus one:

```
int res = Math.pow(10, length) - 1;
```

Comment: Oh wow! Thanks, this works perfectly! I'll accept as soon as I can.

Comment: That's not going to work very well when `length > 9` (max int value is less than 10^10).

Comment: @TedHopp `BigInteger` would help, though :)

Answer (score 3):

You could do this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while (length-- > 0) {
    sb.append('9');
]
nines = sb.toString();
```

Or, if `nines` is an `int`:

```
nines = 0;
while (length-- > 0) {
    nines = 10 * nines + 9;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way:

```
String nines = "";
for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  nines += "9";
}
return Integer.parseInt(nines);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by creating a String with the correct number of numerical characters, then parse it into an `int`. Something like this...

```
String bigNumber = "";
for (int i=0;i<length;i++){
    bigNumber += "9";
    }
int intNumber = Integer.parseInt(bigNumber);
```

However, note that there are limits to the size of the `int`. I would recommend that you...

1. Perhaps try using something that can hold larger numbers, such as `long` (realising that `long` still has a limit, but its a higher limit than `int`).
2. Provide error checking - if there are too many characters or the number is too big, show an error to the user, rather than crashing your application.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not opposed to including another library, you could use Apache Commons Lang `StringUtils.repeat` http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#repeat(char, int)

```
String nines = StringUtils.repeat('9',length);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since we're at it...

```
char[] nineChars = new char[length];
Arrays.fill(nineChars, '9');

String nines = new String(nineChars);
```